# TypeScript i get error message showing that this.registerNumber is undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, undefined

this.registerNumber is showing the value of Undefined I declared it has a string and putting data in it using message service. Message Service is fetching the data but the value of register number remains undefined.
TypeScript, I get an error message showing that this.registerNumber is undefined.

```
export class OtpSlideComponent implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild("otpInput", {static: false}) otpInput;
    otp: string;
    otpReceived: boolean = true;
    showOtpComponent: boolean = true;
    opened: boolean = false;
    timeLeft: number = 45;
    send: boolean = false;
    interval;
    showMe: boolean = false;
    registerNumber: string;
    config = {
        allowNumbersOnly: true,
        length: 4,
        inputStyles: {
            width: "30px",
            height: "40px",
            border: "0px",
            "border-radius": "0px",
            "border-bottom": "1px solid #A9A8A8",
            outline: "none",
            "margin-left": "20px",
            background: "transparent"
        }
    };

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        public toastrService: ToastrService,
        public messageService: MessageService,
        public dataService: DataService
    ) {
        this.otpVerify = this.fb.group({
            otp: [""]
        });
    }

    otpVerify: FormGroup;
    slideRight: any = "right";

    ngOnInit() {
        if (  //undefined this.registerNumber //
            this.messageService.getData() &&
            this.messageService.getData()["registerPhone"]
        ) {
            this.registerNumber = this.messageService.getData()["registerPhone"];
        }
    }


    toggleAnim() {
        this.slideRight = this.slideRight == "left" ? "right" : "left";
    }

    mobileRegister() {
        const self = this;
        const data = {
            mobileNumber: this.registerNumber,
            OTP: parseInt(this.otp)
        };
        this.dataService.verifyOTP(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: console.log this.messageService.getData() please

Comment: You should check the condition for setting `this.registerNumber`. This condition will probably never be reached.

Comment: If you show the MessageService or even the part that handled getData() we could probably provide a more accurate solution.

Comment: the issue was with ngOnInit() it was taking time to fetch data after MessageService was called and    this.registerNumber remain undefined. It is solved when i used another lifecycle hook

Comment: @Ryuk That is not the solution. This will technically solve your problem but it will lead you to a myriad of other problems down the line, and an altogether lack of understanding. Your problem is that you're not subscribing to your data response. If you'd have provided the information I asked for, I could have explained what exactly is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

this.messageService.getData() or this.messageService.getData()["registerPhone"]; maybe null which cause it to not to go in If loop so **registerNumber** remain undefined